# Reusing decorated path

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am currently trying to create a freehand style as seen in technical drawings:

[image: image of a technical drawing with a part cut out]

(see the thin line to the right of the shaded part)

This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586063/reusing-decorated-path

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.pathmorphing}

\tikzstyle{freehand}=[decoration = {random steps, amplitude = 10}]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick] (0, 0) rectangle (6, 3);
    \draw[thin, freehand, decorate] (3, 0) -- (3, 3);
    \fill[red, opacity = .5] (0, 0) -- (3, 0) decorate [freehand] { -- (3, 3)} -- (0, 3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This somewhat does what I want:

[image: reproduction of the technical drawing in tikz with an issue]

However, the line and the background don't match.

I think I can fix this through either

1. setting a random seed to the same value for both parts
2. use `filldraw` from the beginning
3. name the random path & reuse it for the fill command

I couldn't find any way to do 1.

2 I don't like because there could be situations where I want to fill both sides of the lines.

So my question is, how do I save a morphed path to reuse it later?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Applying the duplicate to your case would be something like `\pgfmathsetseed{10}
    \draw[thin, freehand, decorate] (3, 0) -- (3, 3);
    \pgfmathsetseed{10}
    \fill[red, opacity = .5] (0, 0) -- (3, 0) decorate [freehand] { -- (3, 3)} -- (0, 3);`.

Comment: But to fill both sides of the line you could also fill the rectangle first and then draw the second fill on top I guess (but I didn't try that).